# conda command doesn't work despite changing the bashrc file

Tags: bash, arch-linux, i3, installer-anaconda

I am running Manjaro i3wm. I have installed anaconda to my machine but despite changing the bashrc file, I can't run conda commands on the Manjaro terminal or the PyCharm terminal. I've done this before but I'm not sure whether I'm the one making a mistake or if the process is different with i3.

This is the path of my anaconda bin: `~/Downloads/anaconda/pkg/anaconda/opt/anaconda/bin`. I've installed anaconda through AUR into my Downloads folder. And here is what I have in my bashrc file:

`export PATH=~/Downloads/anaconda/pkg/anaconda/opt/anaconda/bin:$PATH`

but I can't execute conda commands. I know that this isn't specifically a manjaro issue so I apologize for that. I was just wondering if I'm the one making a mistake or if the process is different with i3 (that is, if I need to change anything in the config file)

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda seems to work differently in manjaro I've installed it yesterday and also struggled a little I'm able to run it with:

```
source /opt/miniconda3/bin/activate
```